# How would I check if created_at and update_at are on the same day?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, controller

In my rails model, I have the standard `created_at` and `updated_at` variables generated by rails. In my view, I want to display text only if the *days* are equal.

```
<% if @post.updated_at == @post.created_at %>
    ...
<% else %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

This obviously won't work. Would there be a way to access the day, month, and year components of each datetime? Would I need to make a method in my controller?

In other words, how can I check if the datetime of both variables share the same day, month, and year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert datetime to date object like below

```
<% if @post.updated_at.to_date == @post.created_at.to_date %>
```